# How to list my active shortcut keys

Tags: shortcut-keys

How do I get a list of my active shortcut keys?

I want to avoid overwriting an existing key combination when I define custom shortcut keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hit <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Type "keyboard" (no quotes).
3. Click on the Keyboard Shortcuts icon.
4. Click the Add button.
5. Enter a name (*Update Manager*) and a command (`update-manager`) and click Apply
6. Click the Disabled <kbd>button</kbd> in the new entry which will then ask for the new keyboard shortcut.
7. Click the keyboard shortcut you want to
8. Apply to the action.
9. Click **Close** to close the keyboard shortcut window. Test your new keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you Nimishan. Is there a way I can copy the list of (currently defined) shortcut keys into a text file?

Comment: Try the below link. http://producthelp.sdl.com/sdl%20trados%20studio/client_en/Setting_Preferences/SpecifyKSs.htm